# How to change the number of displayed items using just CSS depending the width of the screen?

Tags: css, responsive-design

Is there a technique for display all `li` elements on big screen, and reduce the its quantity on mobile view using just css3? Here is my live example what I want to achieve [link](https://jsfiddle.net/rk87k9gb/1/). I would like to show all elements in normal view (large screen) and reduce the quantity of displayed list items for smaller screens.

I made two separated lists, one for large screen, second for mobile. I'll use `@media` queries to display one of them and hide second depending the sreen size.
Is it possible to keep the same effect using just one `ul` list?

```
<ul class="large-screen">
  <li>...<li>
  <li>...<li>
  <li>...<li>
  <!-- more li -->
</ul>
<ul class="small-screen">
  <li>...<li>
  <!-- less/just few li -->
</ul>
```

Is the better way to do this using just css?
[image: Example]

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best way to do this is using media queries. You'd need only one list (not two seperate) and define the layout under a media query.

Take a look at this for more information on media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Once you've tried some things and it doesn't work out, you can come back to us with your troubles.

happy coding!

Comment: Thanks, @victoria-s I know how to use `@media` queries. In other words, Here is the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/rk87k9gb/1/embedded/result/) describing my question. I know how to use @media queries but I don't know how to display one `li` on **small-screen**. Should I set `display: none` for everything that's not `:first-child`?